# Ответ из Express на запрос из другого домена

Tags: node.js, express

На ноде подключён `express` с таким кодом:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('server started')                    
    })
app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.send('{a:1}');
})
```

Клиент запущен на местном VSCode порт 5500 с livereload.
Node+Express запущен на этой же машине на порту 3000
В файле index.html клиента есть кнопка с обработчиком:
Пытаюсь получить запрос из express  с другого порта, по определению из другого домена.

```
getBtn.onclick =() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/')
        .then(res => {
             return res.text();    
        }).then((txt)=>{
            console.log(txt);
        }) 
    }
```

При клике запрос обрабатывается, и нода отправляет res, но клиенту прилетает  undefined. Если в консоль вместо res.text() получать res `.then(res => {console.log(res)})`, то в консоль прилетает объект с `body:null`, `stasus: 0`, `ok: false`, однако, в консоли на вкладке `network>Preview` ответ `{a:1}`, Response в статусе `200`, `ok: true`

Почему ответ на клиенте пустой?

---

(UPD) В комментариях были подсказки, код сейчас работает, вопрос поправлен.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `res.text()` написать `res.json()`

Comment: В режиме no-cors нельзя получить ответ

Comment: В клиент добавил headers: {'Access-Content-Allow-Origin':'*'}
На ноде добавил cors().
Результат тот же.

Comment: Поправьте текст в вопросе в соответствии с новыми вводными

Comment: на getBtn.onclick не `.then(res => { res.text(); })`, а **return res.text()** или без скобок {}

Comment: Заголовок `mode: no-cors` убрал, с ним в ответе возвращается пустое тело. На клиенте оставил без заголовка.
На ноде установил cors, использовал его по умолчанию. Вопрос в том, что в функции обработчике надо писать `return res.text()`, обычный res.text() возвращает Promise, доставать оттуда тело = костыль. 
Почему так, не понял, было бы здорово, если бы нашёлся добротный ответ.
Вопрос подправляю с новыми данными, мне, возможно кому-нибудь ещё будет интересен ответ.

Comment: @nörbörnën
Да, поставил, вопрос поправил. Осталось понять почему `return`.
Напишите ответ, поставлю в решение.

Comment: @nörbörnën
В принципе понятно, потому что функция не вызвана, а выражение будет вызвано. Вопрос выяснен, напишите ответ, поставлю в решение. Благодарю.

Comment: почитайте https://learn.javascript.ru/promise-chaining

Comment: и https://learn.javascript.ru/arrow-functions-basics что бы понять зачем там `return`